# Option selected using form_multiselect in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using code igniter's `form_multiselect` for my profile form. I want to show the selected value in select box after submit. Used code is like this:

```
form_multiselect('brand[]', $brand_list,'id="brand"');
```

I have tried `set_multiselect` but doesn't work. can any one help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the third parameter an array of selected values like:

```
form_multiselect('brand[]', $brand_list, array('small', 'medium'), 'id="brand"');
```

Comment: happie to help buddy ! :D @user2537981